# Awk to get the attribute value from XML file

Tags: bash, shell, awk

For getting the attribute value from the below mentioned xml for attribute code from tag c

random.xml

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c id="123" code="abc" date="12-12-2022"/>
        <c id="123" code="efg" date="12-12-2022"/>
        <c id="123" date="12-12-2022"/>
    </b>
</a>
```

Currently the logic is:

`cat random.xml | egrep "<c.*/>" | awk -F1 ' /code=/ {f=NR} f&&NR-1==f'  RS='"'`

How does the above logic work to get the values of **code** from tag **c**?

Getting the expected output:

```
abc
efg
```

Comment: Just for clarification: So the question boils down that you have in awk a field containing a string of the form `foo="bar"`, and you want to extract _bar_ from it. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Yes your understanding on the issue is correct @user1934428

Comment: In this case, it is solely question about awk programming and the xml context is irrelevant. May I suggest that you edit the question then so that it reflects only the problem at hand, dropping the whole xml stuff. Having said this: As you can see from the awk man page, the functions `split`,  or alternatively `substr` (perhaps combined with `index`) would be an obvious solution. Did you consider using one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly observe that

```
cat random.xml | egrep "<c.*/>" | awk -F1 ' /code=/ {f=NR} f&&NR-1==f'  RS='"'
```

is of dubious quality, as

- `egrep` does not require standard input, it can read file itself, so you have useless use of `cat`
- simple pattern is used in `egrep` which will work equally well in common `grep`, no need to summon ehanced grep, this usage is overkill
- `1` is set as field separator in `awk`, but code does not make any use of fields mechanism

after fixing these issue code looks following way

```
grep "<c.*/>" random.xml | awk ' /code=/ {f=NR} f&&NR-1==f'  RS='"'
```

How it does work: select lines which contain `<c` followed by zero-or-more any characters followed by `/>`, then instruct `awk` that row are separated by qoutes (`"`) when row does contain `code=` set `f` variable value to number of row, print such row that `f` is set to non-zero value and `f` value is equal to current number of lines minus one, which does mean `print` rows which are directly after row containing `code=`.

Observe that GNU `AWK` is poorly suited for working with XML and using regular expression against XML is very poor idea, as XML is not Chomsky Type 3 contraption.

If possible use proper tools for working with XML data, e.g. [`hxselect`](https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/man1/hxselect.html) might be used following way, let `file.xml` content be

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c id="123" code="abc" date="12-12-2022"/>
        <c id="123" code="efg" date="12-12-2022"/>
        <c id="123" date="12-12-2022"/>
    </b>
</a>
```

then

```
hxselect -c -s '\n' 'c[code]::attr(code)' < file.xml
```

gives output

```
abc
efg
```

Explanation: `-c` get just value rather than name and value, `-s '\n'` shear using newline, i.e. each value will be on own line `c[code]` is CSS3 selector meaning any `c` tag with attribute `code`, `::attr(code)` is `hxselect` feature meaning get attribute named `code`. Observe that this solution is more robust than peculiar cat-egrep-awk pipeline as is immune to e.g. other whitespace usage in file (whitespaces outside tags in XML are optional).

Answer (score 2):

This might be an `awk` question but parsing XML should be done with XML tools.

Here's an example with Xidel (available [here](https://nightly.link/benibela/xidel/workflows/main/master) for a few OSs) and a standard XPath expression:

```bash
xidel --xpath '//c[@code]/@code' random.xml
```

<sup>**note:** `//c[@code]` selects the `c` nodes that have a `code` attribute, and `.../@code` outputs the value of the `code` attribute.</sup>

###### Output

```
abc
efg
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input always looks likes the sample XML then you can make the `code` attribute itself a field separator, and `<` the record separator, so that you can easily extract the value as the second field when the first field is the tag name `c`:

```
awk -F' .*code="|" ' -vRS='<' '$1=="c"{print $2}'
```

Demo: https://awk.js.org/?snippet=Lz6yx7